# Different environment variables on git bash and windows cmd

Tags: python, windows, git, bash

I have a python file in which I'm using the `subprocess` module to execute some command line scripts.
I'm using [Git bash](https://git-for-windows.github.io/) to run this python file. In the file, I execute the script:

`KG_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8900`

This script sets the variable successfully when I run it manually on the git bash command line.
But when I execute this using the python file, it gives me the following error:

`'KG_URL' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.`

I tried digging deeper into this and I found out that executing the python file on git bash is the equivalent of running those scripts on the Windows cmd. When I tried running the set command without parameters (to get the current environment variables) on the Windows cmd, I found out that the variable KG_URL does not exist. But when I ran the same command on git bash, I can see that KG_URL exists.

Any idea why this discrepancy exists? And how can I solve this issue?

The reason why I'm executing these scripts in a Python file is because I need to convert it into an exe later. Assuming that all environments where I run this exe will have git bash installed, is there any way of ensuring that these scripts run only through git bash, and not the Windows cmd?

Comment: How are you trying to use this environment variable?  Please show your code.  The error message suggests you are trying to use it as a command or program.  You can force `bash` to be used by prefixing your command with `bash -c`.

Comment: Preferably use the fully-qualified path to Git bash. Otherwise in Windows 10 systems you may end up running WSL bash. Also, you should know that setting the `KG_URL` environment variable in a child process has no effect on the parent Python process.

Comment: This is the line in the python file which has the script:
subprocess.Popen("KG_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8900", shell=True)

Comment: I tried what @eryksun suggested. 

subprocess.Popen(export_line, executable="C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe")

This just opened a new git bash window to execute this. And as he said, it did not have any effect on the parent Python process.

Is there a way for me to run a bunch of scripts in an open Git bash window, from a python file, and not a .sh file?